# bash ls; output a time of modification of files including year and seconds

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I want to output a time of modification of files including year and seconds. I tried to use ls -linT, means -T must do it, but it doesn't. -T is recognized as tabulation size.
I'm searching a solution using ls. Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try `--time-style=full-iso`, or just `--full-time`:

```
ls -l --time-style=full-iso
ls --full-time
```

From man-page:

> --time-style=STYLE
>                 with  -l,  show  times  using  style  STYLE: full-iso, long-iso, iso, locale, +FORMAT.  FORMAT is interpreted like `date'; if
>   FORMAT is FORMAT1<newline>FORMAT2, FORMAT1 applies to non-recent files
>   and FORMAT2 to recent files; if STYLE  is  prefixed  with`posix-', 
>   STYLE  takes effect only outside the POSIX locale

So you can also have a format specifier (see `date` man-page for format string):

```
ls -l --time-style=+"%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: On Mac, it's `ls -T` in case anyone wanted to know.

Comment: On Solaris, it's `ls -lE` in case anyone wanted to know.

Comment: @hobbes3 ls -lT on current OSX

Comment: ls: illegal option -- -
ls: illegal option -- -
ls: illegal option -- y
ls: illegal option -- =
ls: illegal option -- +
ls: illegal option -- %
ls: illegal option -- Y
ls: illegal option --  
ls: illegal option -- %
ls: illegal option -- :
ls: illegal option -- %
ls: illegal option -- M
ls: illegal option -- :
ls: illegal option -- %

Comment: @ДеянДобромиров it is obvious that something is wrong with you `ls`. are you running this on an embedded device?

Comment: No, Linux /Name_here/ 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 10:22:33 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux